# Does Python'3 http.client library support persistent, keep-alive connections?

Tags: python, http

The [documentation for the http.client library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) says nothing about it, but the API itself seems to imply that it does support keep-alive connections, allow you to start a connection and then issue multiple requests to it.

Can someone confirm that it does indeed work, and whether it is automatic or configuration is necessary to get it working?

Comment: This is not an answer at all, but have you tried the requests library. It does most http client stuff very brilliant http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ Saved me so much time already

Comment: What happened when you tried? Did you get any errors? Show your code.

Comment: @Ana from the link I just posted: "Requests Keep-alive and HTTP connection pooling are 100% automatic"

Comment: I'm looking for a way to not use libraries not already included with Python.

Comment: @kindall are you serious about this? what code would you use? I believe it is not easy to distingush if the library makes a new ceonnection all the time. OK, if you are not just coding you could invent some setup. But isn't it valid to ask the fellow coders?

Comment: Yes, I'm serious. It is pretty trivial to determine whether a persistent connection is being used using any network monitor software (Wireshark, etc.) which you probably already have on hand if you're doing network programming.